# Menu-Toggle does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to customize a Baamboo Weebly theme and have everything down, except for some reason the "menu-toggle" does not work when looking on mobile or responsive view.

Can't figure it out, please help.  Here is the preview of my site:

http://preview.editmysite.com/3n1549.f2420e041d00d88c2bf8bf32f6b32214

Comment: Honestly, I have not tried anything because it is out of my area of knowledge.  I can usually get around CSS and HTML pretty well but this looks like it involves JQuery.

Comment: I was hoping someone could look at the preview link and inspect it and see where the issue is.  I am a bit out of territory with this.

Comment: Is it possible you did not move all the files over like Jquery to you host? Were you able to use it prior to moving to weebly..

Comment: Weebly did some updates and now it is not working, cant figure out what changed or what i need to change to make it work.

Comment: I see Jquery is loading but no script to call on the menu to toggle. Maybe you turned it off by accident? If you go to the Themes tab and click on "Change Theme", you should see an option to the right to show custom themes. Design choices and header/background images are all tied to a theme. You may have to end up contacting the maker of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this and change the names to match your id or class.

```
$(function() {
$('.navbar').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#sidebar').is(':visible')) {
    $('#sidebar').animate({
      'width': '0px'
    }, 'slow', function() {
    $('#sidebar').hide();
});
    $('#main-content').animate({
    'margin-left': '0px'
    }, 'slow');
    } else {
$('#sidebar').show();
$('#sidebar').animate({
    'width': '210px'
  }, 'slow');
     $('#main-content').animate({
    'margin-left': '210px'
     }, 'slow');
   }
 });
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/xk0n1ccz/)